Check render method of SafeAreaInsetsContext.Consumer, Element type is invalid: expected str (built-in comp) or class/func (composite comp)but got:Num
I am using react-native-safe-area-context@4.10.8
migrating react-native- 0.71.1 => 0.74.0
After building app gives above error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.  Check the render method of SafeAreaInsetsContext.Consumer.
"dependencies": {
    "@alessiocancian/react-native-actionsheet": "^3.2.0",
    "@dudigital/react-native-zoomable-view": "^1.1.4",
    "@openspacelabs/react-native-zoomable-view": "^2.1.6",
    "@rbmweb/canvas": "^1.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.3.2",
    "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "^1.4.2",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.1.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.6.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "2.2.6",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^5.24.1",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^7.0.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1659.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "clevertap-react-native": "^2.2.1",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.2.0",
    "fast-text-encoding": "^1.0.6",
    "i18n-js": "4.4.3",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "link-preview-js": "^3.0.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.7.2",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-audio-recorder-player": "^3.6.10",
    "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-blob-util": "^0.19.9",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1305.0",
    "react-native-check-version": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "^8.2.2",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-create-thumbnail": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^11.1.0",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.3.0",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-fs": "2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.41.2",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-localize": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-mathjax": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.25",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.5",
    "react-native-permissions": "^4.1.5",
    "react-native-pinch-zoom-view": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-print": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-radial-gradient": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.14.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "3.32.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view-improved": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "15.3.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-user-avatar": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.7",
    "react-native-video": "6.3.0",
    "react-native-video-controls": "2.8.1",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-vimeo-iframe": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-vlc-media-player": "1.0.67",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.10.4",
    "react-native-wheel-pick": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-windows": "0.74.13",
    "react-native-youtube-iframe": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "9.1.2",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.1.7",
    "redux": "5.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "3.1.0",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
    "victory-native": "37.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.7.5",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.7.7",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.85",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.74.85",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.74.85",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.85",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.15",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-web": "^0.18.10",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },

Component-
<SafeAreaInsetsContext.Consumer>
        {insets => (
          <View
            style={[
              styles.mainView,
              {
                paddingTop: insets.top,
                paddingBottom: insets.bottom,
                backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
              },
            ]}>
                <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => handlePrivacyPolicyPress()}
              style={[styles.bottomImageView, {bottom: insets.bottom}]}>
              <View style={styles.emailViewStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.emailTextStyle}>{privacyPolicy}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => handleEmailPress()}
              style={[styles.bottomImageView, {bottom: insets.bottom+30 }]}>
              <View style={styles.emailViewStyle}>
                <Vector height={normalize(20)} width={normalize(20)} />
                <Text style={styles.emailTextStyle}>{supportEmail}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          
            {
              showPrivacyModal && 
              <PrivacyPolicyModal isVisible={showPrivacyModal} onClose={handlePrivacyPolicyPress} />
            }

            {isForgotPasswordScreen && (
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{position: 'absolute', top: 100, left: 10}}
                onPress={() => {
                  navigation.goBack();
                }}>
                <BackButton />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )}
            <View style={{margin: normalize(40), alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Logo width={normalize(192)} height={normalize(65)} />
            </View>
            <ScreenComponent {...props} />
          </View>
        )}
      </SafeAreaInsetsContext.Consumer>

I tried by changing different versions of react-native-safe-area-context.
Currently "SafeAreaInsetsContext.Consumer" implemented in functional component, I tried by changing it to class component.
Checked name and default exports.
